PGP decryption in azure fucntion app v2-linux
I am trying to decrypt a file using python gnupg. I have an azure durable fucntion app on Linux app service.
The code runs fine on local but fails on Cloud.
decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt(encrypted_data, passphrase='mypassphrase').

I am getting the error no secret key
The code to import keys is
private_key_bytes = base64.b64decode(self.pgpkey)
gpg = gnupg.GPG(verbose=True)
import_result = gpg.import_keys(private_key_bytes,passphrase=self.config.keypassphrase)

I can ssh to the function app and can list keys. But I only see public keys. It appears the gpg agent is not running.
Below is the error I am getting when I ssh into the function app
root@a56ftf:/# gpg --list-secret-keys
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/.gnupg'
gpg: error running '/usr/bin/gpg-agent': exit status 2
gpg: failed to start agent '/usr/bin/gpg-agent': General error
gpg: can't connect to the agent: General error

I have tried ssh onto the function app. seems the gpg-agent is not able to run


Remove installed gnpug using the command:

apt-get remove gnupg -y

root@47622021c49a:/# apt-get remove gnupg -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dirmngr gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm libassuan0 libksba8 libnpth0 pinentry-curses
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnupg
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 885 kB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 29288 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gnupg (2.2.27-2+deb11u2) ...



Run below commands to install gnupg again:

apt-get install -y gnupg gnupg1
cp -a /usr/bin/gpg /usr/bin/gpg2
ln -sf /usr/bin/gpg1 /usr/bin/gpg



I could fetch the keys using the command gpg --list-secret-keys:


